# Azure Event Hub Python SDK

Tags: python, azure, mqtt, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventhub

Can anyone explain how to use the "Event Hub-compatible name" and "Event Hub-Compatible endpoint" using the python event hub SDK. The SDK asks for

```
# Address can be in either of these formats:
# "amqps://<URL-encoded-SAS-policy>:<URL-encoded-SAS- 
# "key>@<mynamespace>.servicebus.windows.net/myeventhub"
# "amqps://<mynamespace>.servicebus.windows.net/myeventhub"
ADDRESS = os.environ.get('EVENT_HUB_ADDRESS')

# SAS policy and key are not required if they are encoded in the URL
USER = os.environ.get('EVENT_HUB_SAS_POLICY')
KEY = os.environ.get('EVENT_HUB_SAS_KEY')
```

I need help fitting the strings given under the default endpoint into this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you mention "Event Hub-compatible name" and "Event Hub-Compatible endpoint", I assume you are trying to connect to an IoT hub's Event Hub-compatible endpoint.

With this **Event Hub-compatible name**: `iothub-ehub-getstarted-99999-xxxxxxxxxx`
and this **Event Hub-Compatible endpoint**: `Endpoint=sb://ihsuprodbyres999dednamespace.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=iothubowner;SharedAccessKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=`

Then the **EVENT_HUB_ADDRESS** looks like this: `amqps://ihsuprodbyres999dednamespace.servicebus.windows.net/iothub-ehub-getstarted-99999-xxxxxxxxxx`

For **EVENT_HUB_SAS_POLICY** and **EVENT_HUB_SAS_KEY** values, you can use either the **iothubownwer** or **service** as the SAS policy along with it's corresponding key. You can find these in the portal on your IoT hub's **Shared access policies** page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive the device-to-cloud messages from IoT Hub built-in endpoint with the latest Azure Event Hub Python SDK, there is another option, you can refer to following code:

```
import os
import sys
import logging
import time
from azure.eventhub import EventHubClient, Receiver, Offset

PARTITION = "0"

total = 0
last_sn = -1
last_offset = "-1"

client = EventHubClient.from_iothub_connection_string("{iot hub connection string}", debug=True)

try:
    receiver = client.add_receiver("$default", PARTITION, operation='/messages/events')
    client.run()
    start_time = time.time()
    for event_data in receiver.receive(timeout=100):
        last_offset = event_data.offset
        last_sn = event_data.sequence_number
        print("Received: {}, {}".format(last_offset, last_sn))
        total += 1

    end_time = time.time()
    client.stop()
    run_time = end_time - start_time
    print("Received {} messages in {} seconds".format(total, run_time))

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    client.stop()
```

I think if there is no 
particular reason,it is better to use IoT Hub own specific Python client library to receive the messages.